# Ruby on Rails remote_form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a contact form using the remote_form_tag, but I cannot get it to work.

```
    <% remote_form_tag :url => {:action => :email_create} do %>
     <%= label_tag 'name', 'Name: ' %><%= text_field_tag :name %>
     <%= label_tag 'email', 'Email: ' %><%= text_field_tag :email %>
     <%= label_tag 'message', 'Message: ' %><%= text_area_tag :message %>
     <%= submit_tag 'Send' %>
    <% end %>
```

The problem is that code throws errors.

Anyone have any idea what the problem is?

Thank you

Comment: When you say "throws errors", it's usually a good idea to paste in an example of one. This could be caused by anything.

Comment: Sorry, This is the error: undefined method `remote_form_tag' for #<ActionView::Base:0x5d15fec>

Comment: WHat Rails version are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Rails 2.3.x, there is no `remote_form_tag` method.

Use `form_remote_tag` instead (if you aren't wrapping the form around a model).

Answer (score 7):

`remote_form_tag` has been removed in Rails 3. You need to use `form_tag` in combination with the `:remote => true` option.